# Как вывести атрибуты товара woocommerce в списке товаров?

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование, woocommerce

Доброе утро. Подскажите как вывести атрибуты товаров в таком виде: 
[image: Макет]

Я добавил вариативный товар. В самом товаре добавил атрибут с названием **Количество** и со значениями *1 шт | 250 гр | 500 гр | 1000 гр*

И для каждого значения добавил свою цену, а в файл **functions.php** добавил следующий код:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'show_attributes', 20 );

function show_attributes() {
  global $product;
  $product->list_attributes();
}
```

И он у меня вывел только **значения** атрибутов (без цен) и в одну строку, а хотелось бы как у меня в psd в разных ячейках и с ценами

Comment: Вы писали свой вопрос два месяца назад, надеюсь, что Вы уже смогли найти на него решение. Если так и есть, прошу Вас написать решение, это очень помогло бы не только мне, но и всем, кто столкнулся с подобной проблемой

Answer (score 0):

Решение находится в шаблоне woocommerce/templates/single-product/product-attributes.php

Можете кастомизировать как угодно этот шаблон, предварительно перекинув его в папку woocomerce в своем шаблоне.